# 8 speed Quando rear hub rotating in both directions

Tags: shimano

The 8 speed Quando rear hub of bike rotates in both the direction. can it be repaired or needs to be replaced? Please advise what's the issue.

Comment: The freewheel mechanism is failing.  This is often due to the grease in the mechanism getting too sticky, and sometimes spraying the innards with WD40 or some such will fix it.  Sometimes it must be disassembled to one degree or another.  And sometimes it's cheaper to just replace the wheel.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the advice. The hub itself is rotating both ways. So do I need to replace the hub itself?

Comment: Coz the repair said the hub needs to be replaced.

Comment: Note that if you must replace the hub it's usually cheaper to replace the entire wheel.